# Can I have same tag for two UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, tags, uibutton

I have two buttons, which changes position based on some condition.

Instead of changing the position programmatically, what I am planning is have two buttons and based on condition show and hide those buttons.

After that, what I am planning is have same tag to both buttons and based on tag I would be calling actions.

My plan is, if any of both button is pressed (as we have same tag), one action will get called without writing code two times for both buttons to call action.

***So my question is, is it fine if I have same tag for two buttons?***

Comment: Yes, it's fine. But if you're going to use the tag to decide on `calling actions`, why not just connect the actions to the button? Is there a lot of common code? Would you be better refactoring that common code into another method?

Comment: @Wain : I am doing this inside tableview and hence wanted to do through programmatically..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tag` is completely user defined and has no implication on the function of the button. It's purely for your identification. So you could assign the same tag to all of your buttons if you'd like with no functional repercussions (except that your tags would be meaningless).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just adding the same action to both buttons?

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(yourAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(yourAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```